# Certain keys on my keyboard click other keys

Tags: 12.10, keyboard

For example, when I press backspace, F7 triggers. T also triggers it. This did not happen in Windows 8. Please help. I'm using a generic keyboard by Ativa.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a different keyboard layout. Check which one you are using on settings and then switch to the relevant one.